# MySQL: Is It Possible To Restrict Rows via WHERE Clause When Using GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I need to count rows that contain a date value entry. The row is initialized to `0000-00-00` and gets populated with a date later in my app process based on an event

I want to count how many rows have a date entered in the date field -- DATE2 by each group date.

```
ID  DATE1      DATE2
001 2012-10-01 0000-00-00
002 2012-10-04 2012-09-15
003 2012-10-03 0000-00-00
004 2012-10-04 2012-09-26
005 2012-10-01 2012-09-27
006 2012-10-02 0000-00-00
007 2012-10-02 2012-09-19
```

So I need the result (based on this simple example) to be:

```
2012-10-01 = 1 row
2012-10-02 = 1 row
2012-10-04 = 2 rows
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select DATE1, count(*) 
from MyTable 
where DATE2 <> '0000-00-00' 
group by DATE1
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8ff99/1)

Comment: Ok thanks @RedFilter - I neglected to specify that I needed the result to be grouped. So I amended my question.

Comment: Ok, thanks @RedFilter. Are you sure that works? I got syntax errors from MySQl -- maybe I had something else wrong but I wanted to confirm that I could use WHERE and GROUP BY together.

Comment: Ok, thanks @RedFilter. My syntax must be wrong elsewhere. Appreciate your help and time.